# SCALA: Function for Square root of BigInt

Tags: scala, square-root

I searched internet for a function to find exact square root of BigInt using scala programming language. I didn't get one, But saw one Java Program and I converted that function into Scala version. It is working but I am not sure, whether it can handle very large BigInt. But it returns BigInt only. Not BigDecimal as Square Root. It shows there is some bit manipulation done in the code with some hard coding of numbers like `shiftRight(5), BigInt("8") and shiftRight(1)`. I can understand the logic clearly, But not the hard coding of these bitshift numbers and the number 8. May be these bitshift functions are not available in scala, and thats why it is needed to convert to java BigInteger at few places. These hard coded numbers may impact the precision of the result.I just changed the java code into scala code just copying the exact algorithm. And here is the code I have written in scala:

```
   def sqt(n:BigInt):BigInt = {
      var a = BigInt(1)
      var b = (n>>5)+BigInt(8)
      while((b-a) >= 0) {
          var mid:BigInt = (a+b)>>1
          if(mid*mid-n> 0) b = mid-1
          else a = mid+1
         }
      a-1
   }
```

My Points are:

1. Can't we return a BigDecimal instead of BigInt? How can we do that?
2. How these hardcoded numbers `shiftRight(5), shiftRight(1) and 8` are related 
   to precision of the result.

I tested for one number in scala REPL: The function `sqt` is giving exact square root of the squared number. but not for the actual number as below:

```
scala> sqt(BigInt("19928937494873929279191794189"))
res9: BigInt = 141169888768369

scala> res9*res9
res10: scala.math.BigInt = 19928937494873675935734920161

scala> sqt(res10)
res11: BigInt = 141169888768369

scala>
```

I understand `shiftRight(5) means divide by 2^5 ie.by 32 in decimal` and so on..but why 8 is added here after shift operation? why exactly 5 shifts? as a first guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question 1 and question 3 are actually the same question.

> 1. How [do] these bitshifts impact [the] precision of the result?

They don't.

> 3. How [are] these hardcoded numbers ... related to precision of the result?

They aren't.

There are many different methods/algorithms for estimating/calculating the square root of a number (as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)). The algorithm you've posted appears to be a pretty straight forward binary search.

1. Pick a number `a` guaranteed to be smaller than the target (square root of `n`).
2. Pick a number `b` guaranteed to be larger than the target (square root of `n`).
3. Calculate `mid`, the whole number mid-point between `a` and `b`.
4. If `mid` is larger than (or equal to) the target then move `b` to `mid` (-1 because we know it's too large).
5. If `mid` is smaller than the target then move `a` to `mid` (+1 because we know it's too small).
6. Repeat 3,4,5 until `a` is no longer less than `b`.
7. Return `a-1` as *the square root of `n` rounded down to a whole number*.

The bitshifts and hardcoded numbers are used in selecting the initial value of `b`. But `b` only has be greater than the target. We could have just done `var b = n`. Why all the bother?

It's all about efficiency. The closer `b` is to the target, the fewer iterations are needed to find the result. Why add 8 after the shift? Because 31>>5 is zero, which is not greater than the target. The author chose `(n>>5)+8` but he/she might have chosen `(n>>7)+12`. There are trade-offs.

> 2. Can't we return a BigDecimal instead of BigInt? How can we do that?

Here's one way to do that.

```
def sqt(n:BigInt) :BigDecimal = {
  val d = BigDecimal(n)
  var a = BigDecimal(1.0)
  var b = d
  while(b-a >= 0) {
    val mid = (a+b)/2
    if (mid*mid-d > 0) b = mid-0.0001  //adjust down
    else               a = mid+0.0001  //adjust up
  }
  b
}
```

There are better algorithms for calculating floating-point square root values. In this case you get better precision by using smaller adjustment values but the efficiency gets much worse.

Comment: Good explanation jwvh. Can we make the so called `hardcoded values 5(shifts) and 8 in terms variables based on the size of n` that is passed to the function? or Can you suggest the best algorithm for very large numbers?

Comment: A "good explanation" but still not worthy of an up-vote? (Wow. Tough audience.) Your follow-up questions are interesting but no longer specific to Scala code. You might want to take it to a [group that specializes in this sort of thing](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> Can't we return a BigDecimal instead of BigInt? How can we do that?

This makes no sense if you want exact roots: if a `BigInt`'s square root can be represented exactly by a `BigDecimal`, it can be represented by a `BigInt`. If you don't want exact roots, you'll need to specify precision and modify the algorithm (and for most cases, `Double` will be good enough and much much much faster than `BigDecimal`).

> I understand shiftRight(5) means divide by 2^5 ie.by 32 in decimal and so on..but why 8 is added here after shift operation? why exactly 5 shifts? as a first guess?

These aren't the only options. The point is that for every positive `n`, `n/32 + 8 >= sqrt(n)` (where `sqrt` is the mathematical square root). This is easiest to show by a bit of calculus (or just by building a graph of the difference). So at the start we know `a <= sqrt(n) <= b` (unless `n == 0` which can be checked separately), and you can verify this remains true on each step.

Comment: All this boils down to `finding two closest expressions a and b in terms of n, such that a<n and b>n to reduce number of iterations. Are there any such established(proved) expressions better than n/32 +8 for b   and also for  a 
 instead of taking a crude guess of 1`

Comment: By `Exact` what I mean is for very very large BigDecimal numbers, even much larger than a `Double` represents(`309 digits or so`),  Suppose if n is a BigDecimal with 10000 digits and 20 digits after decimal point. and ` r is its square root`, then r^2 (` r squared` ) must match at least upto ten digits when compared to original n, `however big the passed n is`.. If this is my requirement, how I should go about taking a `better algorithm` and `specification of precision` in the algorithm.

Comment: For context, since this might not have been clear to everyone from the original post, any positive integer either has an integer square root or the square root is irrational. (If it is irrational, it cannot be represented exactly by a BigDecimal). https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/12/20/roots-of-integers/